# Is there any way to change your close reason?

Tags: discussion, closing

I've marked a question for closing, but I've realised it is incorrect.

Is there any way to change your close reason? *Without retracting your current close vote?*

---

### My case is:

I've flagged this poorly written question ([MINECRAFT WILL NOT WORK](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/212597/minecraft-will-not-work)) for closing, but for the wrong reason.

> **unclear what you're asking**
> Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Except, it's a clear duplicate (since it's asking for a Minecraft error code solution) that's already covered.

> **duplicate of...**
> This question has been asked before and already has an answer.

And it's the duplicate of... [Is there a list of error codes for Minecraft?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/96496/is-there-a-list-of-error-codes-for-minecraft)

> ### RuntimeException: No OpenGL context found in the current thread. or
>
> ### org.lwjgl.LWJGLException: Pixel format not accelerated
>
> **This means:**
>
> - Your graphics card or driver is unable to handle Minecraft.
>
> **You can try:**
>
> - It could be as simple as updating graphics drivers, but this doesn't happen often.
>
>   - If this error occurs after installing or updating the operating system, you probably have default graphics drivers that do not support
>     OpenGL. Install the drivers provided by your graphics card
>     manufacturer instead of the default drivers.
> - Otherwise, you may need to purchase a newer graphics card for your PC.

---

### The reason being:

You get this message:

> **closed** as too broad by [5 peoples' names] at [Date]
>
> *There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be
> too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set
> or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs. If
> this question can be reworded to fit the rules in the help center,
> please edit the question.*

Instead of a clear message (for the author):

> This question already has an answer here:
> *[Duplicate question] # answers*

Answer (score 1):

When this happens I post the duplicate of message in the comments. Hopefully other users will close the question as a dupe, if not the link is still there.

Comment: I already did :)